# Definitions of operator norm and operators that don't obtain its norm on the set $\{ v \in V:\|v\| \leq1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

**First question:** 
I know that the following definitions of norm of the operator  are equivalent:

$$\begin{align*}
a&= \inf\{ k\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq k\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\},\\
\\
b&=\sup\{ \lVert Av\rVert\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }\lVert v\rVert\leq 1\},\\
\\
c&=\sup\{\lVert Av\rVert\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }\lVert v\rVert = 1 \},\\\\
d&=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Av\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }v\neq 0\right\}.
\end{align*}$$

I found somewhere one more definition (let's call it e ):  $ e = \sup \{ \frac{ ||Av||}{||v||}:  v \in V , ||v|| \leq 1  \} $ . I want to prove that this definition is also equivalent, so can someone just check this method:

I want to  prove that $ a \leq e $ and $ e \leq d$. The second inequality follows because supremum on the subset is smaller, so we just have to prove the first inequality.

$a = \inf \{ k: ||Av|| \leq k||v||,  v \in V   \} $, so it follows that   $||Av|| \leq a ||v|| $ for all $v \in V, ||v|| \leq 1$  and $a$ is the least constant for which this holds.

$ \sup_{v \in V, ||v|| \leq 1}  \frac{||Av||}{||v||}   = e $, so $||Av|| \leq e||v|| $ for all $ v \in V, ||v|| \leq 1 $. Now it follows that  $a \leq e$ and all norms are same now. Is this correct?

**Second question:**
If linear operator does not reach its norm on the set $\{  v \in V:   ||v|| \leq 1\} $  does it mean that it doesn't reach nowhere and conversely?  I think that if there is $v \in V $ such that $||A|| = \frac{||Av|| }{||v|| } $, then we can take $ y= \frac{v}{||v|| } $, $||y||=1$, and $||A||= ||Ay|| $.  Is this reasoning correct? Thank you in advance.